# Http error code for dependent modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, http, httpresponse

I am working on plugins for a web platform.
I have one Core plugin(core library which is required to be installed and enabled) and one functional plugin.
I want when Core plugin is installed but not enabled then the functional plugin not to work. I've always check whether the Core is enabled and want to return it for all kind of requests - json, xml, html, ...

I want to return to the client response with good error code but not sure which one is the best.
I am thinking about 403 or as most people do 500.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Boris

Answer (score 0):

The returned code you should use really depends on semantics of the resource state. The answers to these questions should determine appropriate status code:

- Why the Core is disabled? Is it an error state (something unexpected, that should not happen under normal conditions) or normal state?
- Is the service disabled for all clients or some authorized users could perform the calls?
- Should the client treat current state as temporary or permanent?

Here are some suitable error codes (under certain conditions):

- `403 Forbidden`

  You should use this code only if some of the users still could call the service successfully.
- `500 Internal Server Error`

  This generic error code is far too overloaded. Choose it only if you can't select more specific error code.
- `503 Service Unavailable`

  It's a good candidate if current state is temporary and should be fixed soon.